# How can I use room database deleteAll() when I turn off app in kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-room

I already set roomdatabase for historyactivity, and I can use insert methond. 
now when I click my historyactivity, data still appear to recyclerview items.
but I want reset data when I turn off build app. How can I do it? Anyone can help?
In my DAO, u can see fun deleteAll(), so How can I use it when I turn off my app??
History.kt

```
@Entity(tableName = "history")

class History(@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id: Long?,
              @ColumnInfo(name= "item") var item:String?,
              @ColumnInfo(name = "title") var title:String?,
              @ColumnInfo(name = "price") var price:Int?,
              @ColumnInfo(name = "Image") var Image:String?

) {
    constructor(): this(null,"","",0,"")
}

@Dao
interface HistoryDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM history")
    fun getAll(): List<History>

    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE )
    fun insert(history: History)

    @Query("DELETE from history")
    fun deleteAll(): List<History>
}
```

HistroyDB

```
@Database(entities = [History::class], version = 3)
abstract class HistoryDB: RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun HistoryDB(): HistoryDao

    companion object {
        private var INSTANCE: HistoryDB?=null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): HistoryDB? {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                synchronized(HistoryDB::class) {
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext,
                        HistoryDB::class.java, "history.db")
                        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                        .build()
                }
            }

            return INSTANCE
            }

            fun destoryInstance() {
                INSTANCE = null
            }
    }
}
```

HistoryActivity

```
class HistoryActivity : AppCompatActivity(), SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {




    private var historyDb: HistoryDB? = null
    private var historyList = listOf<History>()
    lateinit var adapter: HistoryitemReclycerViewAdapter


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_history)

        historyDb = HistoryDB.getInstance(this)
        adapter = HistoryitemReclycerViewAdapter(this, historyList)

        val r = Runnable {

            try {
                historyList = historyDb?.HistoryDB()?.getAll()!!
                adapter = HistoryitemReclycerViewAdapter(this, historyList)
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

                swipeRefreshLo.setOnRefreshListener(this)
                recyclerview.adapter = adapter
                recyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
            } catch (e: Exception) {

            }

        }

        val thread = Thread(r)
        thread.start()

    }
    override fun onRefresh() {
        swipeRefreshLo.isRefreshing = false
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        HistoryDB.destoryInstance()
        historyDb =null
        super.onDestroy()
    }


}
```

Comment: Did you check my answer? If it worked for you, please accept it

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need an in-memory database. You can use [`Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Room#inmemorydatabasebuilder) instead of `Room.databaseBuilder`. This is documentation of this Builder:

> Creates a RoomDatabase.Builder for an in-memory database. Information stored in an in-memory
>      database disappears when the process is killed.
>      Once a database is built, you should keep a reference to it and re-use it.